# Knockout.JS foreach nested JSON array

Tags: knockout.js

How can I map it to knockout ? I'm extracting it using jquery getjson, but I got no idea how to map and bind it.

Im quite new to knockout and I'd appreciate some guidings.

How do I continue ? I'd appreciate any help !

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the mapping plugin. It works very well mapping JSON into a view model.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: I've mapped it myself creating specific models. Thank you anyways, Sir !